# how to invoke or get the sub-property value from Properties Tab in cypress

Tags: cypress

How to invoke the sub-property value from the properties tab. I need to get the value of the `error.JPG` in from Properties Tab

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

I tried with these different codes changes

```
cy.get('div [data-text-as-pseudo-element="error.JPG"]').invoke('prop','dataset').should('contain','error.JPG')
```

---

```
cy.get('div [data-text-as-pseudo-element="error.JPG"]').invoke('prop','dataset').should('contain','DOMStringMap')
```

---

```
cy.get('[data-text-as-pseudo-element="error.JPG"]').invoke('prop', 'dataset').then(dataset,()=>{
        cy.wrap(dataset).invoke('prop','textAsPseudoElement').should('contain','error.JPG')
    })
```

---

I'm getting Assertion Error

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but domstringmap given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

> The dataset read-only property of the HTMLElement interface provides read/write access to custom data attributes `(data-*)` on elements. It exposes a map of strings (DOMStringMap) with an entry for each `data-*` attribute.

Your Cypress test can just treat it as a conventional attribute

```js
cy.get('my-selector')
  .should('have.attr', 'data-text-as-pseudo-element', 'error.JPG')
```

The tests you propose above are already complete with just this

```js
cy.get('div[data-text-as-pseudo-element="error.JPG"]')
```

because the browser guarantees the attribute will be added to `dataset`.

---

If you want to work further with dataset in Javascript just chain the properties, e.g

```js
cy.get('div[data-text-as-pseudo-element="error.JPG"]')
  .should($el => {
    const attrValue = $el[0].dataset.textAsPseudoElement
    expect(attrValue).to.eq('error.JPG')  
  })
```

Comment: `cy.get('div[data-text-as-pseudo-element="error.JPG"]')
  .should($el => {
    const attrValue = $el[0].dataset.textAsPseudoElement
    expect(attrValue).to.eq('error.JPG')  
  }) `
This worked for me

Comment: I did realize it is there but I still tried to access it from Properties Tab

Comment: Ok, but note the "Properties Tab" is just the browser dev-tool's representation of the element's javascript properties. If you think of it that way, it becomes easier to work out.